# LocalStorage data - how to save it on page, after delete them in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, single-page-application

same question, as in title. I have some data in LocalStorage, and I just display it on the page. How can it still be seen on page, after I delete it from LocalStorage? Should I save it somewhere? I can't find answer to my question anywhere.

Comment: can u add some code snippet till which extend you coded ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the information to a local variable using let, cont (depending on your scope requirements). 

If you wish to save it on the client machine , there are several options. Please look at this link below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage